# Installing jupyter with Python 3.8 fails with "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" because it's using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

On a mac, I've installed Python 3.8 and I am trying to install jupyter using:

```
pip install jupyter
```

It runs, but I get the following output in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Seems odd as I am on Python 3.8 and the output seems to refer to Python 2.7.

Anyway, when I then try

`jupyter notebook`

Still, the command `jupyter` is not found.

Comment: Try running `pip3 install jupyter` instead.

Comment: "*I am on Python 3.8*" Well the logs say that you are not. On macOS, the `python` command normally refers to the built-in Python 2.7. There is no details how you installed Python 3.8, but you have to make sure you are using the correct interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error

> ```
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve  
>    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)  
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60  
>    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
> ```

you can see that the `pip` you used is from the Python 2.7 installation. The latest pip 21.0 will not work on that version, and f-strings are only available starting Python 3.6.

The installation failed by the way, so trying to use `jupyter` command after that would, of course, still not work.

> Seems odd as I am on Python 3.8 and output seems to refer to Python 2.7

You will *always* have to *explicitly* indicate which Python version you want to use. Since macOS comes with a built-in Python 2.7 installation, you'll have to *explicitly* indicate the Python 3 specific one, usually `python3` and `pip3`.

Depending on how you installed your Python 3.8, best practices are:

1. Using the [`<python> -m pip`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) command, which means "use the `pip` that comes from this `<python>` installation". (You can check the version with `python -V`)

   ```
   ~$ python3 -V
   Python 3.9.1

   ~$ python3 -m pip install jupyter
   ```
2. Creating a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#virtual-environments-and-packages) and [installing your packages inside the virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#managing-packages-with-pip)

   ```
   ~$ python3 -V
   Python 3.9.1

   ~$ python3 -m venv myenv

   ~$ source ./myenv/bin/activate
   (myenv) ~$ python -V
   Python 3.9.1
   (myenv) ~$ python3 -V
   Python 3.9.1

   (myenv) ~$ pip install jupyter
   ```

   The virtual environment takes care of using the correct Python versions and `pip install`-ing things also uses the correct versions. Compared to option 1 which installs things system-wide, the packages you installed in a virtual environment will only be available when you activate the virtual environment.